# How to Display Woocommerce Notices with shortcode?

Tags: php, woocommerce, shortcode

```
function display_woocommerce_notices() {
wc_print_notices();
}
function woocommerce_notices_shortcode() {
ob_start();
display_woocommerce_notices();
return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('woocommerce_notices', 'woocommerce_notices_shortcode', 999);
```

I am using above code with elementor page builder to display Woocommerce notices after add to cart and all messages.
The shortcode is not working [woocommerce_notices] .

I want to display success, error messages on add to cart.
Here is the page
https://dmmotionarts.com/product/valentines-day-hot-air-balloon-memories-ae-template-tiktok-reel-version/

Currently, it will show the notices but it is done by using a widget. I want to do it with a shortcode.